# match files in sub directories only - python

Tags: python, subdirectory, os.walk

I have a folder system like so:

- Root

  - Mixtape 1

    - mp3s
    - sub-dir/

      - mp3s
  - Mixtape 2

    - mp3s
    - sub-dir/

      - mp3s
  - Mixtape 3

    - mp3s
    - sub-dir/

      - mp3s

I'm looking to create a list of all mp3 files (from the sub-dir's only) and then play a random mp3 from that list.

So, i have come up with the following code:

```
import os
import random
import subprocess

# Set the root dir for mixtapes
rootDir = 'mixtapes'

# Function to make a list of mp3 files
def fileList(rootDir):
    matches = []
    for mixtape, subdir, mp3s in os.walk(rootDir):
        for mp3 in mp3s:
            if mp3.endswith(('.mp3', '.m4a')):
                matches.append(os.path.join(mixtape, mp3))
    return matches

# Select one of the mp3 files from the list at random
file = random.choice(fileList(rootDir))

print file

# Play the file
subprocess.call(["afplay", file])
```

However, this code pulls in all .mp3 or .m4a files recursively... I only want them if they're contained within the 'sub-dir'.

So, how do i go about modifying the fileList function to only append the mp3 if it's within a sub-dir?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the obvious? check for it:

something like (didn't check it for exact synatx)

```
for mixtape, subdir, mp3s in os.walk(rootDir):


    for mp3 in mp3s:
        if os.path.dirname(os.path.join(mixtape, mp3)) == rootDir:
        continue
```

Comment: If this were obvious to the OP, they wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Meant no offence to the OP, but I think he is looking for a builtin method or something like that

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is the following modification to fileList():

```
def fileList(rootDir):
    matches = []
    for d1 in next(os.walk(rootDir))[1]:
        for d2 in next( os.walk(os.path.join(rootDir, d1)) )[1]:
            for mixtape, subdir, mp3s in os.walk(os.path.join(rootDir, d1, d2)):
                for mp3 in mp3s:
                    if mp3.endswith(('.mp3', '.m4a')):
                        matches.append(os.path.join(mixtape, mp3))
    return matches
```

For clarification, this idiom:

```
next(os.walk(some_dir))[1]
```

...returns a list of subdirectory names inside some_dir.

In other words, the above code first dives down two levels into the folder heirarchy before searching for mp3s.

Also, if you don't have any subfolders within each "sub-dir" folder, then you can use os.listdir() instead of os.walk() at that point in the function, since there are no further subfolders to traverse.